# Error in the Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, statistics, classification, naivebayes

I try to write code to use `Naive Bayes classifier`. But it works uncorrectly.
My data is a data about quantity of views of profile in social networks from some id and determination is it really `id` of some person

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import defaultdict
from math import log

def train(samples):
    classes, freq = defaultdict(lambda:0), defaultdict(lambda:0)
    for feats, label in samples:
        classes[label] += 1                 # count classes frequencies
        for feat in feats:
            freq[label, feat] += 1          # count features frequencies

    for label, feat in freq:                # normalize features frequencies
        freq[label, feat] /= classes[label]
    for c in classes:                       # normalize classes frequencies
        classes[c] /= len(samples)

    return classes, freq                    # return P(C) and P(O|C)

def classify(classifier, feats):
    classes, prob = classifier
    return min(classes.keys(),              # calculate argmin(-log(C|O))
        key = lambda cl: -log(classes[cl]) + \
            sum(-log(prob.get((cl,feat), 10**(-7))) for feat in feats))

def get_features(sample): return (str(sample)[2:5],)

samples = (line.decode('utf-8').split() for line in open('sample.txt'))
features = [(get_features(feat), label) for feat, label in samples]
classifier = train(features)

print 'Is it real ID: ', classify(classifier, get_features(0.132))
```

`samole.txt` is a

```
0.019546345 1
0.009769094 0
0.000888099 0
0.004440497 0
0.009769094 0
0.000888099 0
```

When I try `print 'Is it real ID: ', classify(classifier, get_features(0.132))` it has always returned `0`.
Where I have an error?

Comment: What do you expect the method get_features to return? It returns the 2nd - 4th characters in the string, not the last letter as noted in the comment.

Comment: @Conor, I use it to determine `names` `men or women` and get last letter. But now I want to determine numbers. If I write value, like in the `sample.txt`, it returns `1`, but it others `0`

Comment: I'd recommend you print out some intermediate values, including the input parameters to the classify method and check that they really are as you expect. It's difficult to follow what you're trying to do given the way you pass around lambda functions